# Can't add new Azure user to old VSO GIT repo

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

​We have a GIT repo that was made when it still was called 'VisualStudioOnline'.

It has 2 users who are token granted. This works fine.

We now have a new user, which I also want to give access. When I now go to the GIT url: https://MyOrg.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MyWebApp I get a 401 Unauthorized.

When I go to http://www.visualstudioonline.com I'm redirected to Azure DevOps. And still can't log in.
In my Azure Portal I have the new user in the AAD, but I can't link him to the GIT Repo. I can't even find my GIT Repo in the Azure Portal.

When I go to https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg I get the message `Your account, ... is not authorized to view this page`. But I'm logged as the Azure admin.

How can I give access to my GIT repo to my new colleague?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​Yesterday I tried a lot of options. Giving roles and adding groups to the Azure Admin user, but nothing changed.

Today I was making screenshots to show my settings and now it is working. Not sure what was changes but it looks like Azure needs some time before changes in rights are implemented.

Thanks to @starian and @Hugh for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First you can check if your organization is connected to AAD in the user profile.
[image]

If you want to invite external users to your organization, you need to meet this prerequisite : You must set the policy **External guest access** to **On** for the organization that you want to invite external users to.
[image]

For details , you can refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

Contact to your DevOps organization administrator (not azure admin) to add these accounts and specify corresponding team project.

[image]